# div not in proper place

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am creating a one-pager website. I am facing problem in the positioning of divs in the body tag. In the code, the search button is suppose to take me where the div containing the id "search" is , but this  is somehow overlapping with the previous div with the id of "home". I checked all the previous tags as to make sure they are closed but I am unable to figure out where the problem lies. Also my background images wont show up for these div tags.Any help would be highly appreciated...Below is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>eVolunteers</title>
<!--links-->
<link rel="icon" href="http://static.tmimgcdn.com/img/favicon.ico"><!--the title image-->
<link href="css/indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.tmimgcdn.com/img/favicon.ico">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://openfontlibrary.org/face/dancing" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home">
<div  style=" width:460px;height:180px;  display: inline-block; float:left ;"><p class="heading" style="padding-top:50px; ">eVolunteers</p>
</div>
<div  style= " width: 800px; height:180px;  display: inline-block; float:right; " >
  <ul class="ls" >
   <li><a href="#home" class="round yellow">Home<span class="round">That is, if you already have an account.</span></a></li>

   <li><a href="#search" class="round agreen">Search<span class="round">That is, if you already have an account.</span></a></li>

  <li><a href="#contact" class="round purple">Contact<span class="round">That is, if you already have an account.</span></a></li>

  <li><a href="#about" class="round gray">About Us<span class="round">About the developers.</span></a></li>

  <li><a href="login.html" class="round green">Login<span class="round">That is, if you already have an account.</span></a></li>

  <li><a href="signup.html" class="round red">Sign Up<span class="round">But only if you really, really want to. </span></a></li>

</ul> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--slider-->
<div id="search" class="sb">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="cb">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="about" class="ab">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
</body>
        </html>
```

and this is the css

```
.sb{
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding-top: 800px;

}

.cb{
    border: 5px solid green;
    background: url('homepage.jpg');
    }


.ab{
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.heading { 
   font-family: 'DancingScriptOTRegular'; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-style: normal; 
   font-size: 60px;
   text-align:right;
}

.ls{
padding-left: 60px;
}
/* login and sign up css*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -o-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }



    ul {
        margin: 30px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
    }

    @-o-keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
    }

    .round {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 30px;      
        text-decoration: none;      
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;        
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);
        letter-spacing: -.065em;
        font-family: "Hammersmith One", sans-serif;     
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        border-radius: 300px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    .round:hover {
        width: 130%;
        height: 130%;
        left: -15%;
        top: -15%;
        font-size: 33px;
        padding-top: 38px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        z-index: 2;
        border-size: 10px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }

    a.red {
        background-color: rgba(239,57,50,1);
        color: rgba(133,32,28,1);
        border-color: rgba(133,32,28,.2);
    }

    a.red:hover {
        color: rgba(239,57,50,1);
    }

  a.yellow{
     background-color: rgba(255,255,0,1);
        color: rgba(255,165,0,1);
        border-color: rgba(255,165,0,.2);
  }

a.yellow:hower{
    color: rgba(255,255,0,1);

}

  a.agreen{
   background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    color: rgba(0,128,0,1); 
    border-color: rgba(0,128,0,.5);
}

    a.yellow:hower{
    color: rgba(255,255,0,1);
    }

    a.green {
        background-color: rgba(1,151,171,1);
        color: rgba(0,63,71,1);
        border-color: rgba(0,63,71,.2);
    }

    a.green:hover {
        color: rgba(1,151,171,1);
    }

    a.purple{
     background-color: rgba(221,160,221,1);
        color: rgba(128,0,128,1);
        border-color: rgba(128,0,128,.8);
    }

    a.purple:hover {
     color: rgba(221,160,221,1);
   }

   a.gray{
    background-color: rgba(169,169,169,1);
        color: rgba(3,3,3,1);
        border-color: rgba(3,3,3,.2);
   }

   a.gray:hover {
    color: rgba(3,3,3,1);
   }

    .round span.round {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        font-size: 1px;
        border: none;
        padding: 40% 20% 0 20%;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .round span:hover {
        opacity: .85;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -o-text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);  
    }

    .green span {
        background: rgba(0,63,71,.7);       
    }

    .red span {
        background: rgba(133,32,28,.7);     
    }

    .yellow span{
    background: rgba(255,165,0,.7);
   }

  .agreen span{
     background: rgba(0,128,0,.7);
  }
  .purple span{
     background: rgba(128,0,128,.9);
  }
  .gray span{
     background: rgba(3,3,3,.9);
  }

    /*slider*/
     #slides {
      display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any accompanying Javascript for your code? Also, why do you want to have two separate references to jQuery? Any reason why you need both versions?

Comment: Oh, just saw that. No, the later version is fine for me, just removed the first one as I copied this part from another html page. And no, there is no accompanying Javascript code .

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still a bit unclear. What is it that you expect to see happen? What user action (e.g., hover, click) triggers this change you're expecting? Looking at the given code, all I can see is that you're triggering some animation effects.

Comment: The div problem is solved, however, my background images do not appear for these divs. In the given code I have declared background attribute in the cb class which doesn't seem to work. I have already tried using background-image attribute but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has to do with your content in `#home` being floated. When you float something it takes it out of the normal document flow. Since the child elements of `#home` are floated `#home` ends up collapsing, that is, having no height.

With the CSS you have provided you can see that your `search` DIV is already at the top of your page based on the red border you have given it. So there is no reason for it to "jump down" to `#search` as it's at the top.

I recommend using a the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) so your `#home` DIV takes up the space you expect it to. There are other options out there but I'll leave that up to you to discover.

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}    
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

In the jsFiddle below I have removed the padding from `#search`, which is also styled by your `.sb` class, and added the padding to your `#home` DIV (for illustrative purposes) as `padding-bottom: 800px;`. I've added the clearfix to `#home` to clear the floats contained within it.

```css
#home {
    padding-bottom: 800px;
}
.sb {
    border: 5px solid red;
    /* moved padding to #home as bottom padding for illustrative purposes */
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="cf">
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mct84jbj/1

Comment: No problem, just updated answer and fiddle to demonstrate the jump better.